# Referencing a pivot table in a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that I created using the following code:

```
SELECT
          [CustomerNUM]
          , [Typez]
          , [States]
          , ([Liquid]) AS 'Qual_Liq'
          FROM (SELECT 
          CustomerNUM
          , Typez
          , States
          , PersonID
          , Balances
          FROM [MyDataTable]) AS a
PIVOT(SUM(Balances) for PersonID
          IN([Liquid]
          ) 
          ) AS pvt;
```

My goal is to reference this pivot to join to another table. Is this possible? I tried exporting the table, but it has not worked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can either use it as a common table expression, or as a derived table like below:

As a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
  <<insert your query here>>
)
select * from cte
```

or as a derived table

```
select * from ( <<insert your query here>> ) table_alias
```

and then you can join other tables to it just like it was an ordinary table.